# How to highlight the unmatched data to its right in the same file using fortran or shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, fortran

After a lot of effort I could not find any suitable command to get my requirement. I have two different data files with one column but unequal lengths. Part of my both files are:

```
file1.dat   file2.dat
 23.99       23.99
 45.950      45.951
 5           6
 23          23
             43
             34
```

I am looking to highlight the unmatched data up to 2 decimal point in same files as given below:

```
file1.dat                   
 23.99               
 45.950              
 5        not present
 23                  

file2.dat
 23.99
 45.951
 6        not present
 23       
 43       not present
 34       not present
```

Comment: Several tools do this for you (tkdiff, meld, vimdiff come to mind).  However, SO is not a place to make lists of tools, but to answer questions on how to solve problems.

Comment: I just started learning Linux. Someone suggested me Linux can make it easier. I tried with diff file1.dat file2.dat > myfile.dat. But it is not giving my result. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion @ThomasDickey

Answer (score 3):

Several tools do this for you (tkdiff, meld, vimdiff come to mind). However, SO is not a place to make lists of tools, but to answer questions on how to solve problems.

vimdiff is not the same as diff.  It is a script using vim to display differences, which you may have available.  There are several examples which a web search on [display highlighted diff](https://www.google.com/search?q=display+highlighted+diff&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) would find easily.
These pages mention some tools:

- *[Top 4 File Difference Tools on UNIX / Linux – Diff, Colordiff, Wdiff, Vimdiff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/linux-file-diff-utilities/)*
- *[Useful but Unknown Unix Tools: How wdiff and colordiff help to choose the right Swiss Army Knife](http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/Debian/CoolTools/wdiff-colordiff.html)*
- *[Useful but Unknown Unix Tools: dwdiff better than wdiff + colordiff](http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/Debian/CoolTools/dwdiff.html)*

But there would be fewer sources of information on how to construct a program which does this.

Some might use [`wdiff`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/manual/wdiff.html) internally, for instance.  It is not (and was not) the only tool of this kind, as I noted [here](http://invisible-island.net/personal/oldprogs.html#freec), but is well-known.  Some (such as [numdiff](http://www.nongnu.org/numdiff/)) do not use `wdiff`).  Consider it a later version of [`spiff`](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Text/spiff-1.0/man.html) (which is still accessible, though I recall problems with it).

If I were developing a script to do what was requested, I would recommend that it produce output in `diff -u` format.  That would let you reuse the `colordiff` program, solving about half the problem.  Then, I would do this:

- filter each of the input files to a temporary file, dropping the digits past the second decimal point,
- run `diff -u` on the temporary files,
- read back the result from `diff -u` and use the *line number* information to merge in the original lines.

That last step would take an experienced developer 2-3 hours to write, so presenting an example is out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

i did simple script it can help you or other 
first we will combine file1.dat with file2.dat and output both to file called output.dat with two columns seems to be like this

```
|23.99 : 23.99|
|45.950 : 45.951|
|5 : 6|
|23 : 23|
| : 43|
| : 34|
```

with paste with awk

```
:|paste -d ' :  ' file1.dat - file2.dat > output.dat | awk -F '|' '{print "|" $1 "|" $8}' output.dat
```

then going to compare between two columns with highlighted arrows with

```
awk -F : '{if(!($1==$2))printf("%s", "'$RED'=>'$NORMAL'not");print" matched ",$0}'  output.dat
```

colors of highlighted arrows

```
RED=`echo -e '\033[41m\033[37m'`
NORMAL=`echo -e '\033[0m'`
```

the result will be like this

```
 present  23.99 :23.99
=>not present  45.950 :45.951
=>not present  5 :6
 present  23 :23
=>not present   :43
=>not present   :34
```

full script :

```
#!/bin/bash
RED=`echo -e '\033[41m\033[37m'`
NORMAL=`echo -e '\033[0m'`


:|paste -d ' :  ' file1.dat - file2.dat > output.dat | awk -F '|' '{print "|" $1 "|" $6}' | awk -F : '{if(!($1==$2))printf("%s", "'$RED'=>'$NORMAL'not");print" present ",$0}'  output.dat
```

Comment: That would show full-line differences, not the partial differences OP requested with *"up to 2 decimal point"*.  (If it were that simple, I would have mentioned colordiff and programs like that).

Comment: but i Merged two files into another output.dat one file as a two columns then compared between these two columns .

Comment: Comparing up to two decimal places of  `45.950 : 45.951`  would ignore the third decimal place and say that the rest of the comparison is equal.  Your comment about merging and columns does not appear relevant to that.  If OP is more interested in learning how to, rather than just using a tool, those would be interesting reading material.

Comment: @authprivate Thanks for your script. Roselover solved it as per my requirement.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thank you very much for your suggestions and supports. Now Roselover's program made it successful.